# Matlab Installation "finished"?

Tags: installation, 13.04, matlab

Hi I am trying to install MATLAB in my Ubuntu 32-bit 13.04 by mounting the ISO. Here are  the steps i followed:

```
sudo mkdir /media/matlab/
sudo mount /home/"username"/Desktop/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au.iso /media/matlab/ -t iso9660 -o loop 


sudo mkdir /usr/local/matlab/
sudo /media/matlab/install
```

After all theese commands i get the following message:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished
```

It is supposed to open a window with the "Matlab installation" but it does nothing.
EXTRA: i read somewhere that if i put -v after the install command it would show me more information about it so here it is:

```
    Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /media/matlab
->  ARCH                = glnx86
->  DISPLAY             = :0.0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_2980/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_2980/bin/glnx86

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_2980/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java  -splash:"/media/matlab/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_2980/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_2980/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_2980/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_2980/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_2980/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_2980/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/media/matlab" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_2980" 

Installing ...
Finished
```

Does anyone know why the installation window isn't showing up?

Comment: The ISO was corrupt

Comment: I had this problem on a fresh 16.04 installation. I made sure all updates were downloaded and did a reboot. That seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

I just found myself in the same situation with the same problem trying to install MATLAB r2014a in a clean ubuntu 14.04, the solution I found it in a post that said that was problem with the java jre

This worked for me:

```
./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/
```

I know you solved with a other iso, but I think someone else can find themselves with the same problem I could be interesting for them.

Comment: Oh my god, you saved my day sir! Thanks so very much!

Comment: `./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have X11 installed

```
apt-get install -y -q libxtst6 libxrender1 libxi6
```

Comment: This is a potential answer to the issue (also posted [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/229857-why-do-i-see-preparing-installation-files-installing-finished-in-the-terminal-window-wh)), though, it could have been worded more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to find the java/jre directory. You can cd to /usr/lib/jvm/ and list all files. There you may find java versions like

`java-8-openjdk
java-8-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.3-openjdk-amd64
java-x-oracle`

You can one as your Java engine.

Personally, I picked the following one and the this command for my MATLAB R2016a installation on Bbuntu 16.04:

`sudo sh ./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/`

You can try different jdk/jre for your case, if you want. Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

After running

```
chmod -R u+x MATLAB_INSTALLER
```

i also installed the JRE for Ubuntu 18.04 using

```
apt-fast install default-jre
```

the graphical installer for MATLAB managed to start on running

```
MATLAB_INSTALLER/install
```

Answer (score -1):

Matlab is installed, it didn't show a window because you didn't add a "-v" extension to it.
Somewhat like this

```
sudo /media/matlab/install -v
```

Comment: Read the question, the OP already did this.