# MATLAB installation error- set X11 display error

Tags: software-installation, xorg, display, matlab

I am desperately trying to install MATLAB on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I followed the instructions given in the pdf manual, however when i ran the command " ./install", it would be followed by three lines:
preparing installation files...
installing...
Finished
and after that nothing happened.
I looked around online to see if anyone else got the same problem and i found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294021/matlab-installation-finished). I tried the solution provided there and used the command:
"
./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/
"
the following error occurred:

Error: Installation cannot proceed. You may either:
1. Set an X11 display, and restart the install process
2. Use the silent install feature by specifying the -mode silent option

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you provided the correct path?

Comment: Yes the path is correct.

Comment: Are you running this from terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) or within XWindows?

Comment: I am running this from termina (Ctrl+Alt+T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Removed the already installed version of jdk-openbox and reinstalled latest jdk and then ran the installer. It worked.
There was some problem with java.

Thanks for your help.