# Matlab 2017b not installing with Ubuntu 2017

Tags: software-installation, matlab

Hello Ubuntu community,

I am a complete newbie to this and encountering some difficulties installing Matlab 2017b on Ubuntu 17. I'm working with the download rather than an iso file and when I run

```
sudo ./install
```

I just get

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished
```

but it doesn't actually install correctly and the installation window never opens. It seems similar to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294021/matlab-installation-finished?newreg=dab3d21b3cbb4dab96047cc232259b7a) but the specific Java jre commands suggested didn't work for me. 
The command to run is given as

```
"/tmp/mathworks_9264/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java" -Xmx512m
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are two Ubuntu 17s: 17.04 and 17.10. Which one do you have?

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I forgot to mention that. I'm running 17.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that this works for me

```
xhost si:localuser:root
sudo ./install
```

Hope it's helpful in case someone else was running into this problem!